# Angular 1.6 ES6 No-error no app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-router

How explaine this ?

Notice: use ui-router
I think is the probleme.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url:'/',
        /*controller:'loginController',*/
        controller: function(){alert('toto');},
        templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

I try this, alert is not display !
before un call myController like :

```
export default function router($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url:'/',
        controller:'loginController',
        templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

in my app.js is defined like that :

```
angular.module('app', [
...
ngRoute,
ngCookies,
appLogin,
...
uirouter,]).config(router);
```

and my Login module:

```
   import loginController from './loginctrl.component.js';
   export default angular.module('appLogin',[])
            .controller('loginController', loginController)
            .name;
```

My page is black, no console errors, no lite-server errors
You can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add run function() :

```
    export default function run($rootScope){
       $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    }
    run.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-im-getting-a-blank-screen-and-there-are-no-errors
show in FAQ !